# Property not found in gradle subproject

Tags: groovy, gradle

I have a simple gradle project that has the following structure:

```
root
|
sampleapp
|  |
|  build.gradle
|
build.gradle
settings.gradle
gradle.properties
```

In my root `build.gradle` I have the following closures:

```
subprojects {
   ext {
     flag = true
   }
   afterEvaluate { subproj -> 
     if(subproj.ext.flag) {
        sampleProp = [
             prop1: "abc",
             prop2: "def"
        ]
     }
   }
}
```

When I run my gradle build, the 'sampleapp' project uses the sampleProp structure, but I get the following exception:

```
Could not find property 'sampleProp' on org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dsl.dependencies.DefaultDependencyHandler_Decorated@7d548fa0.
```

Anything obvious what I am doing wrong?

Comment: You expect sampleProp to be a property of the subprojects or the rootproject?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're trying to add `sampleProp` as a property to the subproject, the following would work:

root project `build.gradle`:

```
subprojects {
    ext {
        flag = true
    }

// This property will be available both at config and exec phases from subproject
    if (ext.flag) {
        println 'yes'
        ext.configPhaseProp = [
                prop1: "defined in root build.gradle",
                prop2: "config"
        ]
    }

// This property will be be available **only** in exec phase
    afterEvaluate { subproj ->
        if (subproj.ext.flag) {
            subproj.ext.execPhaseProp = [
                    prop1: "defined in root build.gradle",
                    prop2: "exec"
            ]
        }
    }

    task HelloFromRoot<<{
        println "######## RootHello"
        println flag
        println "RootHello: $configPhaseProp.prop1 :: $configPhaseProp.prop2"
        println "RootHello: $execPhaseProp.prop1 :: $execPhaseProp.prop2"
    }
}
```

subproject build.gradle:

```
println '########## ConfigTime'
println flag
println "Config: $configPhaseProp.prop1 :: $configPhaseProp.prop2"
//println "Config: $execPhaseProp.prop1 :: $execPhaseProp.prop2" 
//^^ Uncommenting this line will cause a "Could not find property error"

task SubHello << {
    println '########## SubHello'
    println flag
    println "SubHello: $configPhaseProp.prop1 :: $configPhaseProp.prop2"
    println "SubHello: $execPhaseProp.prop1 :: $execPhaseProp.prop2"
}
```

run task HelloFromRoot:

```
########## ConfigTime
true
Config: defined in root build.gradle :: config
:SubProject1:HelloFromRoot
######## RootHello
true
RootHello: defined in root build.gradle :: config
RootHello: defined in root build.gradle :: exec
```

run task SubHello:

```
########## ConfigTime
true
Config: defined in root build.gradle :: config
:SubProject1:SubHello
########## SubHello
true
SubHello: defined in root build.gradle :: config
SubHello: defined in root build.gradle :: exec
```

Comment: that works when the task is defined in the subprojects section of the root, but I have to use these properties in the subproject itself build.gradle. when I reference sampleProp1.prop1 from the child build.gradle, I get an error during evaluation

Comment: I'm able to access sampleProp1.prop1 from subproject build.gradle tasks. Adding subproject build.gradle and outputs to my answer. Are you trying to access it in the configuration phase?

Comment: I am trying to access it under the dependencies section of the child project

Comment: Is there a reason why you have `afterEvaluate` ? Because, by having an afterEvaluate, you're ensuring that `sampleProp1.prop1` wont be available in the subproject during the config phase - updating code to demonstrate this.

Comment: i am working on splitting up a huge project into more smaller ones. Here's what I think is happening. the root project has that afterevaluate block. The settings.gradle, however, includes projects before the actual subproject that needs that property. So I think the property is maybe available after the first project in that list is configured, which works since it doesn't actually reference the property